# Is there a way to store a list when programming a TI-83+?

Tags: ti-basic

Out of curiosity, I'm beginning to learn how to program my TI-83+ calculator. Part of my latest program involves storing numbers in a list. How can I add items to a list on a TI-83+ and how can I loop over them/access them?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to add something to the end, you need the length of the list. Let's say your using L1 as a list and variable A as the value you are trying to add to the list.

Here's what you would do:

```
:A->L1(1+dim(L1))
```

Here's how that works. The dim command has 1 parameter. That parameter is a list. When you use the dim command, it returns the length of the list in the parameters. When you want to refer to a specific place in a list, you use the syntax: list_name(location). So This line of code takes the value of variable A and stores it in the location of L1 which is 1 more than the length of L1, therefore appending variable A to the end of L1.

If you want to access a value in list, again use the syntax: list_name(location). On the other hand, if you don't know the location of the value you are looking for, or you are cycling through the list and doing something with each value, you can use a for statement.

Like this:

```
:FOR(A, 0, dim(L1))
::L1(A)->B
::"do whatever you want with the value of L1(A) here"
:END
```

Or like this:

```
:FOR(A, 0, dim(L1))
::if(L1(A) == "insert value being searched for here"):THEN
:::A->B
:::dim(L1)+1->A
::END
:END
```

The for loop works like this: at the beginning of the loop, 0 is stored to variable A. Then the loop continues until variable A is greater than dim(L1). After each time the loop resets, the value of variable A is increased by 1.

In the first example, the program loops through each value of L1 and does whatever you want to do with each value.

In the second example, the program loops through each value of L1. When the value of L1 matches the value you are looking for, the location of the value is stored in variable B to be used for whatever you want later. Then, the value of variable A is set to 1 more than the length of L1. Since the value of variable A is greater than dim(L1), the for loop is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

An element can be added to the end of a list of unknown length like this:

```
0→L1(1+dim(L1
```

Under normal condition, attempting to set the value of an index greater than the length of the list results in `ERR: INVALID DIM`; however, if the index is only 1 greater than the length of the list, the value is appended to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list or a matrix, but I would suggest a list.  You can find information on lists and their commands from this [link](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/lists).

Lists are also better for saving values in between program executions than just using variables, which may be changes by other programs or math.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to define the size of a list like this :

```
3->dim(L1
```

(if you forget, you will have an ERR:Invalid Dim)

Press enter and you get a "10" as answer (don't worry it's normal).

You can find dim( in the [Catalog] and -> is "[STO->].

Then you could fill the list with some data like this :

```
2->L1(1)
3->L1(3)
```

Now When you print L1 you get :

```
{2 0 3 0}
```

First index is L1(1) not 0 (as usual).

You can delete the list by using DelVar :

```
DelVar L1
```

You can fill it with Fill, sort it, convert to matrix .... 
Simply go to the List menu (2nd + Stat).

You can iterate on the list using a for loop (no foreach, use dim(L1) for the upper bound).

More informations in the [guidebook](http://ti-84-plus.com/ti-84-plus-download.php#guidebooks) or you could also ask your questions on this [calculator questions stack](http://ti-84-plus.com/calculatorquestions/)

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Thibault said, fill it, sort it, convert it (Very well said, by the way). However, you can also do:

```
3->L1(dim(L1))
```

This will add 3 to the end of L1.